# Longtable Issues - Can't compile in sharelatex and it doesn't work well

Tags: errors, longtable, compiling

Good evening,

I was trying to create a longtable with this kind of format. However, every time I try to compile the file with this table, I get a runout error in ShareLatex. What's weirder is that I could compile it before. Here is the longtable I tried to create

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm} p{3.5cm} p{4cm} p{4cm}}
    \caption{Ventajas y Desventajas de los Ensayos No Destructivos.} \label{tab:long} \\
        \toprule
        % aquí añadimos el encabezado de la primera hoja.
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}}{\textbf{Método Empleado}} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}}{\textbf{Campo de Aplicación}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.2cm}}{\textbf{Ventajas}} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.2cm}}{\textbf{Desventajas}}\\[.5ex] \midrule 
        \endfirsthead


        \multicolumn{4}{c}{Sigue en la página siguiente.}
        \toprule
       \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}}{\textbf{Método Empleado}} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}}{\textbf{Campo de Aplicación}} &
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.2cm}}{\textbf{Ventajas}} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4.2cm}}{\textbf{Desventajas}}\\[.5ex] \midrule
        \endhead

        \hline \multicolumn{4}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \
        \endfoot

        % aquí añadimos el fondo de la última hoja.
        \endlastfoot


         \textbf{Termografía}    &    Detección de agua dentro de los paneles de sándwich. Detección de Corrosión.  Detección de delaminación.      &  Capacidad de procesado por imagen, no requiere contacto con el componente, rápido, bueno para detectar acumulación de agua en el panel sándwich.   & Necesita cargarse térmicamente, mediante calentadores de aire, mantas eléctricas, etc. Superficies de protección (como la pintura) puede influenciar (e incluso impedir) su aplicación. No puede repetirse tras un breve espacio de tiempo, penetración térmica limitada, etc. \\[2ex]

          \textbf{Rayos-X}  & Detección de flujo interno y discontinuidades, como son grietas, inclusiones y variaciones de espesor.            & Elimina muchos requerimientos de desmontaje. Tiene una alta sensibilidad y permite grabar los resultados en cámara. & Peligrosidad ante radiación, por lo que se requiere de inspectores y equipamiento especializado. Se requiere fuente eléctrica. La grieta debe estar casi paralela al rayo para ser detectable \\[3ex]

          \textbf{Ultrasonidos}  & Detección de discontinuidades superficial y sub-superficial, grietas y fallos internos en la mayoría de metales son fácilmente detectables con la técnica \textit{pulse-echo}.  & Rápido y fácil de utilizar generalmente. Los resultados se conocen al instante. Elevada precisión. Alta sensibilidad y suelen ser equipos portátiles  & Se requieren operadores cualificados y de fuente eléctrica de alimentación. El plano de orientación de la grieta debe ser conocido a priori para seleccionar el tipo de onda a utilizar. Se requieren también de bloques de referencia para establecer la sensibilidad del equipo \\[3ex]

          \textbf{Corrientes Inducidas}  & Permite la detección de discontinuidades en superficies metálicas, grietas, corrosión intergranular y fallos por sobrecalentamiento (mediante la medida de la conductividad de la zona calentada)  & Simple de aplicar, fácil, detecta discontinuidades de un tamaño muy inferior a otras técnicas, como visual o líquidos penetrantes. Además es rápido y portátil & Sensible ante pequeñas variaciones del material, así como de la propia inspección (efecto \textit{lift-off}). Se requieren de distintos bloques de calibración y probetas para cada material \\[3ex]

          \textbf{Partículas Magnéticas}  & Detección superficial de discontinuidades en materiales ferromagnéticos de cualquier forma o condición de calentamiento.  & Principio en el que se basa simple, fácil de utilizar, portátil, rápido.  & Debe limpiarse la superficie para el testeo. El campo magnético debe ser normal al plano del defecto \\[3ex]

            \textbf{Líquido Penetrante}  & Detección de grietas en la superficie de metales, forjados, soldaduras y partes mecanizadas  & Fácil de utilizar e interpretar, rápido y preciso  & No permite detectar fallos sub-superficiales  \\[3ex]

            \textbf{Inspección Visual}  & Detección de discontinuidades superficiales daños estructurales en todo tipo de materiales  & Simple de aplicar en áreas donde para otro tipo de técnicas sería imposible. Equipamiento óptico permite mejorar este método. & La fiabilidad depende de la habilidad y experiencia del usuario. A veces para acceder a algunos sitios se requiere equipos complejos de tipo óptico.   \\[3ex]

        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem and not just a code snippet. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `longtable` is centered default, so `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center} ` are superfluous. also you forgot `\\ ` after `\multicolumn{4}{c}{Sigue en la página siguiente.}`

Comment: ... and the `\bottomrule` should move up before `\endlastfoot`...

Comment: @Zarko the reason for not using `center` goes deeper than that it's not that longtable is centred by default it has no effect on the horizontal position at all, try `\begin{flushleft}` with  `\begin{longtable}` it does not make it flush left, it just adds spurious vertical space.

Comment: please always provide a full test document that can be tested to reproduce the issue and "doesn't work well" is not very specific, if you get an error message show the full error from the log in a code section.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle,  well, you are the author of the package  :-), you know better than me :-). however, in circumstances  when table width is smaller than text width `longtable`  is centered in text area, isn't it?.

Comment: @Zarko it may be centred or not depending, but wrapping it in `center` or `flushleft` or `flushright` will have no affect on its horizontal position as technically it is always full width.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that your table is to wide for your text width. consequently it spill-out on right text border. you have two choices:

- make column width small, or
- increase text width.

in case, that you increase text width with `\usepackage{geometry}`, than your table is nice centered in text area with your settings of columns width (except of the first column).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % <---
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, longtable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}} % <---
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft}p{#1}}  % <---

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{@{} % <---
        >{\bfseries}L{2cm} R{3.5cm} R{4cm} R{4cm}
                      @{}} % <---
    \caption{Ventajas y Desventajas de los Ensayos No Destructivos.} 
    \label{tab:long} \\ % <--- 
        \toprule
        % aquí añadimos el encabezado de la primera hoja.
    \thead{Método\\ Empleado} % <--- 
        &   \thead{Campo de\\ Aplicación}
            &   \thead{Ventajas} % <--- 
                &   \thead{Desventajas}     \\ % <--- 
        \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \caption{Sigue en la página siguiente.}\\
        \toprule
    \thead{Método\\ Empleado}
        &   \thead{Campo de\\ Aplicación}
            &   \thead{Ventajas}
                &   \thead{Desventajas}     \\
        \midrule
    \endhead
        \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{r}{Continued on next page} \\
    \endfoot
        % aquí añadimos el fondo de la última hoja.
    \endlastfoot
    Termografía
        & Detección de agua dentro de los paneles de sándwich. Detección de Corrosión.  Detección de delaminación.      
            &  Capacidad de procesado por imagen, no requiere contacto con el componente, rápido, bueno para detectar acumulación de agua en el panel sándwich.   
                & Necesita cargarse térmicamente, mediante calentadores de aire, mantas eléctricas, etc. Superficies de protección (como la pintura) puede influenciar (e incluso impedir) su aplicación. No puede repetirse tras un breve espacio de tiempo, penetración térmica limitada, etc.      \\
        \addlinespace
    Rayos-X
        & Detección de flujo interno y discontinuidades, como son grietas, inclusiones y variaciones de espesor.            
            & Elimina muchos requerimientos de desmontaje. Tiene una alta sensibilidad y permite grabar los resultados en cámara. 
                & Peligrosidad ante radiación, por lo que se requiere de inspectores y equipamiento especializado. Se requiere fuente eléctrica. La grieta debe estar casi paralela al rayo para ser detectable               \\
         \addlinespace
    Ultrasonidos
        & Detección de discontinuidades superficial y sub-superficial, grietas y fallos internos en la mayoría de metales son fácilmente detectables con la técnica \textit{pulse-echo}.  
            & Rápido y fácil de utilizar generalmente. Los resultados se conocen al instante. Elevada precisión. Alta sensibilidad y suelen ser equipos portátiles  
                & Se requieren operadores cualificados y de fuente eléctrica de alimentación. El plano de orientación de la grieta debe ser conocido a priori para seleccionar el tipo de onda a utilizar. Se requieren también de bloques de referencia para establecer la sensibilidad del equipo   \\
         \addlinespace
    Corrientes Inducidas
        & Permite la detección de discontinuidades en superficies metálicas, grietas, corrosión intergranular y fallos por sobrecalentamiento (mediante la medida de la conductividad de la zona calentada)  
            & Simple de aplicar, fácil, detecta discontinuidades de un tamaño muy inferior a otras técnicas, como visual o líquidos penetrantes. Además es rápido y portátil 
                & Sensible ante pequeñas variaciones del material, así como de la propia inspección (efecto \textit{lift-off}). Se requieren de distintos bloques de calibración y probetas para cada material               \\
         \addlinespace
    Partículas Magnéticas
        & Detección superficial de discontinuidades en materiales ferromagnéticos de cualquier forma o condición de calentamiento.  
            & Principio en el que se basa simple, fácil de utilizar, portátil, rápido.  
                & Debe limpiarse la superficie para el testeo. El campo magnético debe ser normal al plano del defecto                             \\
         \addlinespace
    Líquido Penetrante
        & Detección de grietas en la superficie de metales, forjados, soldaduras y partes mecanizadas  
            & Fácil de utilizar e interpretar, rápido y preciso  
                & No permite detectar fallos sub-superficiales          \\
         \addlinespace
    Inspección Visual
        & Detección de discontinuidades superficiales daños estructurales en todo tipo de materiales  
            & Simple de aplicar en áreas donde para otro tipo de técnicas sería imposible. Equipamiento óptico permite mejorar este método. 
                & La fiabilidad depende de la habilidad y experiencia del usuario. A veces para acceder a algunos sitios se requiere equipos complejos de tipo óptico.   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

in above mwe (minimal working example) is used the `raqgged2e` package.  using its `\RaggedLeft` and `RaggedRight` macros cells contents are aligned to right and to left respectively.

for column headers is used macro `\thead` provided by `makecell` package. its use significantly shorter table code.

[image]

[image]

(red lines indicate text area border)